# Link building campaign for externally hosted subdomain

Tags: seo, web-hosting, subdomain, link-building

I am launching a link building campaign for a subdomain. I plan to ensure that the subdomain receive enough links from the parent domain and external domains in order to speed up indexing and increase authority, trust, PageRank, etc.

Here is my question: this subdomain is hosted by a different web host than the parent domain. Does this affect SEO for the subdomain?

Answer (score 2):

For the procedure of link building you launched, web hosting of the subdomain won't take into account for SEO. I own multiple websites with your web hosting situation and I have never had problems for SEO.

Moreover, search engines (like Google) currently treat a subdomain as an entirely different domain name for SEO and for sure even more if web hosting is different.